# loops and printing in python

Tags: python, loops

```
num = int(input("Pick a number greater than 1: "))
factorial = 1

if num <2:
    print ("Error please pick a number greater than 1")
elif num >1:
    print ("Please select option 1 or option 2 ")
num2 = int(input("Option 1 will give a countdown to 0, Option 2 will give the factorial. Please Select: "))
if num2 == 1:
 for num in range (num,-1,-1):
  print (num)
elif num2 == 2:
 for i in range (num,1,-1):
  factorial = factorial*i
print("The Factorial is", factorial)
```

If I select option 1  it will also print the factorial  how do I make it so it only prints the countdown to 0  if I select option 1.  If I put the print in the 2nd loop for the factorial  it will print like this
Option 1 will give a countdown to 0, Option 2 will give the factorial. Please

```
Select: 2
The Factorial is 5
The Factorial is 20
The Factorial is 60
The Factorial is 120
```

I don't want that so I put the print outside of the loop  so the factorial will only say one line. But if I put it out the loop  it will print  when I select option 1   what do I do?

Comment: `print` indentation is wrong

Comment: which print indentation is wrong?

Comment: The last line of your code

Comment: yes but if i do that it gets entered into the 2nd loop and it prints like what I posted. How would I get it to only print the factorial is 120

Comment: Okay, I will post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indentation problem in line 15
num = int(input("Pick a number greater than 1: "))
factorial = 1

```
if num <2:
    print ("Error please pick a number greater than 1")
elif num >1:
    print ("Please select option 1 or option 2 ")
num2 = int(input("Option 1 will give a countdown to 0, Option 2 will give the  factorial. Please Select: "))

if num2 == 1:
 for num in range (num,-1,-1):
  print (num)
elif num2 == 2:
 for i in range (num,1,-1):
  factorial = factorial*i
 print("The Factorial is", factorial)
```

Output:

Case : 1

```
Pick a number greater than 1: 6
Please select option 1 or option 2 
Option 1 will give a countdown to 0, Option 2 will give the factorial. Please Select: 1
6
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Case : 2

```
Pick a number greater than 1: 5
Please select option 1 or option 2 
Option 1 will give a countdown to 0, Option 2 will give the factorial. Please Select: 2
The Factorial is 120
```

Comment: Thank you, this is my 2nd week into programming